# Procedurally generated divs are stacking one on top of each other. How can I vertically align them?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a set of divs which generate small table-like structures that will hold a certain amount of information on them. They're defined under the class "**datecontainer**" and are supposed to be aligned to be one above another, like a bullet point list, for example:

- Dataset 1
- Dataset 2  etc. etc.

The problem is, upon being generated by the webpage, the CSS stacks them on top of each other, creating what can only be described as an unholy mess. Currently, I have about five of these datasets on my default testing value.

As it currently stands, I took a very brute-force approach to initially solving it, which required something like 10 line break commands. Obviously this is not a good way to do this, so I was wondering if it was possible to alter my current CSS (shown below) to allow them to align similarly to the bullet point list instead of being one on top of the other.

Here is the HTML/PHP:

```
echo "<div id=left-sidebar>";
$xml=simplexml_load_file("XML.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$id = $_SESSION['P_ID'];

$datequery = "SELECT DISTINCT ProjectDate FROM Dataset WHERE ProjectID = '$id'";
#Validate Query here.

$result = mysqli_query($db,$datequery);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $date = $row['ProjectDate'];
        $datasetquery = "SELECT DatasetNo, Filepath FROM Dataset WHERE ProjectDate='$date' AND ProjectID = '$id'";

        $datasetresult = mysqli_query($db, $datasetquery);
        if ($datasetresult) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datasetresult)) {
                $setno = $row['DatasetNo'];
                $path = $row['Filepath'];
                CreateDatasetContainer($xml, $id, $path, $setno, $date);
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"To add a new dataset for a project, click here\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('ds-pop-up').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('gauze').style.display='block';\"/></div>";
function CreateDatasetContainer($xml, $id, $path, $setno, $date) {
    for ($x=0; $x<count($setno); $x++){
        echo "<div class=datecontainer>
        <div class=\"date\">$date</div>
        <div class=\"dataset\">
        <p><u>Dataset ".$setno."</u></p>
            Filepath: ".$path."<br>
             ";
            if ($xml->syncstat == "Green") {
             echo "Sync Status: <div id=\"circle\" style=background:green></div>";
            }
            else if ($xml->syncstat == "Red") {
             echo "Sync Status: <div id=\"circle\" style=background:red></div>";
            }
            else {
             echo "Sync Status: <div id=\"circle\" style=background:yellow></div>";
            }
            echo "<br>";
            if ($xml->procstat == "Green") {
             echo "Proc Status: <div id=\"circle\" style=background:green></div>";
            }
            else if ($xml->procstat == "Red") {
             echo "Proc Status: <div id=\"circle\" style=background:red></div>";
            }
            else {
             echo "Proc Status: <div id=\"circle\" style=background:yellow></div>";
            }
            echo "<br>
            <form action=\"main.php\" method=\"post\">
                <button type=\"submit\" name=datasetmod value=info id=\"boom\"><img src=img/1469627573_circle-info-more-information-detail-outline-stroke.png></button>
                <button type=\"submit\" name=datasetmod value=edit id=\"boom\"><img src=img/1469627611_hammer_screwdriver.png/></button>
                <button type=\"submit\" name=datasetmod value=destroy id=\"boom\"><img id=\"imgboom\" src=\"img/explosion.gif\"/></button>
                <input type=hidden name=pid value=$_SESSION[P_ID] />
            </form>
     </div></div>"; #About 10 <br> tags went here when I bruteforced it
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Meanwhile, the offending CSS is here.

```
.datecontainer{
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.date{
    border: 4px solid;
    border-color: grey;
    font-size: 20;
}

dataset{
    border: 4px solid;
    border-color: grey;

}

#left-sidebar {
    left:50px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 600px;
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT: I found out what the problem was. It was the HTML/PHP.**

```
<div class=datecontainer>
    <div class=\"date\">$date</div>
</div> <!--EDIT GOES HERE-->
```

**This closing div tag above needed to be placed there, because it was restricting the dataset sizes to 350x50px, which is what was creating the "unholy mess".**

Comment: First you end up with multiple id's that are the same, document id's should be unique. There can be one "circle" for example. Second your inline styles should be like so style="background:red;", notice double quotes. Your classes should also have quotes like so class="example".

Comment: is it working for you `<input type=hidden name=pid value=$_SESSION[P_ID] />` ?

Comment: take a look at `flexboxes` - once you suss them out they make aligning items trivially easy

Comment: @K.I - I'll try fixing that, not sure whether it'll make everything mystically realign itself.  And Festo, that is working fine.

Comment: Ok then, so I figured out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `div`s to behave normally remove `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;` from that class in css. Or create a new class for these `div`s without that bit.

Answer (score 0):

First you end up with multiple id's that are the same, document id's should be unique. There can be one "circle" for example.

Second your inline styles should be like so style="background:red;", notice double quotes.

Your classes should also have quotes like so class="example"

Once you fix these, right click on your page using mozilla and select inspect element, then select CSS and see what CSS needs to be changed, at the moment its a bit messy.

I dont see id #left-sidebar being used anywhere too... maybe its my age...

Comment: Yeah, I realised it's not there either. Lemme edit that real quick.